# date_picker field doesnt show value from database in backpacker 4.1 on laravel 8

Tags: laravel-backpack

When i define a datepicker field in backpack 4.1 on laravel 8 the edit form doesnt show existing value in database and when selecting a new value it doesnt store it.
If i change field to date it all works.
Any ideas ?

New laravel 8 and backpacker 4.1 installation

In model

```
protected $casts = [
    'valid_from' => 'date',
    'valid_to' => 'date',
];
```

No Mutators set.

In Controller in setupcreateoperations

```
$this->crud->addField([
    'name'  => 'valid_from',
    'type'  => 'date_picker',
    'label' => 'Valid From',
    'date_picker_options' => [
        'todayBtn' => 'linked',
        'format'   => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        'language' => 'en'
    ],
    'wrapper'   => [
        'class'      => 'col-md-6'
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Hmm, curious, can you try removing the `$casts` property and adding this `protected $dates = ['valid_from', 'valid_to'];` ? If that works, lemme know and Ill post an answer with more detail and submit a PR to fix the root issue in Backpack.

Comment: Tried that - and it did not work. The existing value in the database is send to the form and is also returned - bit it seems like the value is not beeing binded to the date_picker ? Any ideas ?

Comment: What value are you storing in the database exactly? And can you show the database schema for that column?

Comment: Its a simple - `valid_from` date NOT NULL, The values are dates like "2020-11-17". The value send to the form is <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="date_picker" value="2020-11-17">, so the existing value in the db is send to the form, but not binded to the date_picker jquery ...

Comment: The issue was solved by adding the form-group class to the wrapper. Very odd, but it removed the JS console error "jQuery.Deferred exception: $existingVal is undefined".

Comment: Ahh, this seems to be because in `vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/crud/fields/date_picker.blade.php` it does `$field = $fake.closest('.form-group').find('input[type="hidden"]'),` meaning that as it is now, this field type requires that the `form-wrapper` class be on the wrapper in order for it to find the initial value. Ill post an issue on the git repo and discuss with some of the contributors. There's a few ways we can address that issue. Nice find!

Comment: Hi Wes,Thanks for bringing this forward. /jens

Answer (score 1):

As you found, adding the 'form-group' class back to the field wrapper configuration made the date_picker load normally.

This is happening because in `vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/crud/fields/date_picker.blade.php`

it does

`$field = $fake.closest('.form-group').find('input[type="hidden"]'),`

This means that as it is now, this field type **requires** that the `form-wrapper` class be on the wrapper in order for it to find the initial value. Otherwise, the following check for `if( $existingVal.length )` produces the error below and fails there.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Submitted a [Backpack bug](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/3308) showing the issue and a [Pull request](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/pull/3309) with a fix.

This fix may or may not be merged by Backpack. In the mean time, if you really don't want to use `form-group` on the field wrapper, you can do this:

- copy `vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/crud/fields/date_picker.blade.php` to `resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/fields/date_picker.blade.php`
- inside the new local `date_picker.blade.php`, change the code as follows:

## Old Code

```
        $field = $fake.closest('.form-group').find('input[type="hidden"]'),
        $customConfig = $.extend({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
        }, $fake.data('bs-datepicker'));
        $picker = $fake.bootstrapDP($customConfig);

        var $existingVal = $field.val();

            if( $existingVal.length ){
```

## Updated Code

```
        $field = $fake.closest('.input-group').parent().find('input[type="hidden"]'),
        $customConfig = $.extend({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
        }, $fake.data('bs-datepicker'));
        $picker = $fake.bootstrapDP($customConfig);

        var $existingVal = $field.val();

            if( $existingVal && $existingVal.length ){
```